# Error while loading Combo Box wix

Tags: c#, combobox, wix, windows-installer

I have C# custom action which loads available server certificate into Combo Box. Everything works fine on my side but installer fails running the custom action on client system. Firstly i thought there is some issue at IIS side but later found out that installer throws error when it loads into combo-box.

Following is my C# code:

```
public static ActionResult ListCertificate(Session session)
        {
            session.Log("ListCertificate: Begin");
            try
            {
                int Index = 1;
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

                foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in certificateStore.Certificates)
                {
                    String ApplicationCertificate = certificate.FriendlyName;
                    list.Add(ApplicationCertificate);
                }
                certificateStore.Close();

                List<string> DistinctCertificateList = list.Distinct().ToList();

                View view = session.Database.OpenView("DELETE FROM ComboBox WHERE ComboBox.Property='APPLICATION_CERTIFICATE_NAME'");
                view.Execute();

                view = session.Database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM ComboBox");
                view.Execute();

                foreach (string DistinctApplicationCertificate in DistinctCertificateList)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DistinctApplicationCertificate))
                    {
                        Record record = session.Database.CreateRecord(4);
                        record.SetString(1, "APPLICATION_CERTIFICATE_NAME");
                        record.SetInteger(2, Index);
                        record.SetString(3, DistinctApplicationCertificate);
                        record.SetString(4, DistinctApplicationCertificate);

                        view.Modify(ViewModifyMode.InsertTemporary, record);
                    }
                    Index++;
                }
                view.Close();

                session.Log("ListApplicationCertificate: End");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Record record = session.Database.CreateRecord(2);
                record.SetString(1, session["LISTCERTIFICATE_ERROR"]);
                record.SetString(2, ex.Message);
                session.Message(InstallMessage.FatalExit, record);
                session["ERRORMSG"] = ex.Message;
                session["ERRORSHOW"] = session["LISTCERTIFICATE_ERROR"];
                session.Log("ListApplicationCertificate: exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
```

And my wix UI code is :

```
<Control Id="ApplicationCertificateLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="190" Width="130" Height="15" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.ApplicationCertificateLabel)" />

        <Control Id="ApplicationCertificateComboBox" Type="ComboBox" X="130" Y="185" Width="200" Height="18" Property="APPLICATION_CERTIFICATE_NAME" ComboList="yes">
          <ComboBox Property="APPLICATION_CERTIFICATE_NAME">
            <ListItem Text="[APPLICATION_CERTIFICATE_NAME]" Value="[APPLICATION_CERTIFICATE_NAME]" />
          </ComboBox>
        </Control>
```

I have got following error in verbose log :
**'Function failed during execution. Database: . Invalid update data type in column 2'.**

I have been scratching my head for days. Please help me sort this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "running the custom action on client system".  Does "client system" mean "my customer's server running IIS", or "a PC running a client application"?

Comment: You should really capture the Exception.StackTrace to isolate the line of code that causes the error. The way that catch is coded means it could be almost anywhere in the try - find out exactly which line of code is causing the error!

Comment: As @PhilDW suggested captured exception at `view.Modify(ViewModifyMode.InsertTemporary, record)` and as error message says i think there is some issue at index side.Moreover column 2 is Index only. Is Index datatype the trouble maker here..?